# Disable zoom on Win store app listView

Tags: c#, listview, windows-store-apps

I have a listview databound to a collection of custom controls with images in. It's a part of an app intended for touch only and by default the 2 finger touch on the listview items will cause the entire list view to zoom in or out, enlarging the items inside the listviews controls boundaries. It looks terrible, has no purpose and damages the user experience.

how can I disable the zoom functionality on the listView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the XAML of the ListView, specify:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled" ... >
```